# C++ implementing function for sharedpointer with reference counter

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

getPointer() return the raw pointer of this instance.
getData() returns the data where the instance's raw pointer points to. This returned data/type should be modifiable.
max 3 references should be allowed at a time.

I am doing some practice tasks to better understand c++ :-) been doing them for about 2 months now starting slow for basics to all kinds of other things and now i found this task to "reinvent the wheel of shared_ptr" and i got stuck when trying to implement the functions and decided i would ask for help.

I have used the cpp wiki for shared_ptr operator* and -> and tried to implement that with the functions but am getting expression must have pointer type // expression must have class type and no operator"<<" matches these operands

1. so what i think is that the functions are not delivering back what they are supposed to :-) so i guess i messed up. I tried using this->pData and also pData.get() but still same errors :-(
2. the << error is 100% because i have yet to implement the operator<< in my sharedpointer.cpp

This is my main.cpp

```
#include "sharedPtr.hpp"
#include "Cat.hpp"
#include <iostream>

    int main(void)
    {
        sharedPtr<Cat> newCat(new Cat(0, "Ferrari"));

        // should print "Ferrari"
        std::cout << newCat.getPointer()->getName() << std::endl;

        // should also print "Ferrari"
        std::cout << newCat.getData().getName() << std::endl;

        newCat.getData().score = 50;

        // should printf "50", as it was just assigned before
        std::cout << newCat.getPointer()->score << std::endl;

        // make some copies
        sharedPtr<Cat> copyOfnewCat = newCat;
        sharedPtr<Cat> copyOfnewCat2 = newCat;

        // this copy should fail
        sharedPtr<Cat> copyOfnewCat3 = newCat;

        // should be nullptr
        std::cout << copyOfnewCat3.getPointer() << std::endl;

        // should be something other than 0 and equal
        std::cout << "copy2 pointer: " << copyOfnewCat2.getPointer() << " copy1 pointer: " << copyOfnewCat.getPointer() << std::endl;
        copyOfnewCat2.getData().score = 40;

        // should be 40 now 
        std::cout << newCat.getPointer()->score << std::endl;
        sharedPtr<Cat> copyOfnewCat4(newCat);

        // should be nullptr
        std::cout << copyOfnewCat4.getPointer() << std::endl;
    }
```

My Cat.cpp

```
#include <string>

class Cat
{
public:
    Cat(unsigned int w_score, const std::string& w_name) :
        score(w_score),
        name(w_name)
    {}
    std::string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    unsigned int score;
private:
    std::string name;
};
```

Update exact error message

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0349   no operator "<<" matches these operands main.cpp    31  
Error (active)  E0044   expression must have pointer type   main.cpp    10  
Error (active)  E0153   expression must have class type main.cpp    13  
Error (active)  E0153   expression must have class type main.cpp    15  
Error (active)  E0044   expression must have pointer type   main.cpp    18  
Error (active)  E0349   no operator "<<" matches these operands main.cpp    28
```

These errors are referring to this line in main.cpp

```
// should also print "Ferrari"
    std::cout << newCat.getPointer()->getName() << std::endl;

// should also print "Ferrari"
    std::cout << newCat.getData().getName() << std::endl;
```

Questions

Hmm i think i noticed that i should have my classname at the start of my functions i guess ,so should it be sharedptr& getData and sharedptr* getPointer ?

Comment: Please provide the exact compiler error message and please write a comment in the code marking the line where the error occurs. And please reduce the code to the minimum that is necessary to reproduce the error. [mcve]

Comment: Please put the relevant parts into the question (edit it), not into comments. Thanks.

Comment: @WernerHenze i updated the main question with the error messages
Sorry not really ever used stackoverflow so im sorry im still learning

Comment: You need to replace all "getData()." by "getData()->". Then it compiles on MSVC 2013 and MSVC 2017. What compiler are you using? Can you try "sharedPtr<Cat> newCat = new Cat(0, "Ferrari");"!?

Comment: @WernerHenze

I am using VS2017 pro , yes it works if i replace getData() with getData()-> and getPointer()->score with getPointer().score i dont see the errors.

However i noticed that this isnt the correct way, since i have to use main.cpp as is, only the sharedPtr.cpp is changeable.

So i think the problem is using the operator-> and operator* , i think i have redundancy and should not use these but instead use the getData and getPointer only.

Comment: If you are not allowed to change main.cpp then write this into your question. Don't add it later in a comment. "getPointer()->" works, "getPointer()." does not, if you disagree then something else is not as you write it in your question. Regarding your question why don't you change the signature of getData() to return a T&? That's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Werner Henze has already said everything relevant in his comments, so this is not much more than taking it all and putting it in its right place.

The error is caused by `getData()` returning a pointer and being used as a reference in main. As `getPointer()` already returns the pointer, the fix is to change `getData()` to return a reference:

```
T& getData() {
    return *pData;
}
```

But there are still some possible improvements in your code:

- you have not implemented the limit to 3 references, so your comments are inconsistent
- it does not really make sense to count references for a pointer pointing to NULL (default constructor), because there are no references at all on any object
- a common implementation of the `operator =` is the *copy and swap* idiom. It generally leads to more robust and simple code

Apart from the first remark and after fixing the error, you might ask for a thorough review of your code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - beware, broken code or still not written one is explicitely off topic there...

Comment: Yes i made the changes to the code but the new errors were related to be including the Cats.hpp when i should not have that and i should have included #pragma once 

now the code compiles and its working :-) the problem was as said change return *pData